# how to insert json data to the database from json response in spring mvc

Tags: json, database, spring-mvc

i am working with json data.after successful signup i am getting the json response in the body.now i want to insert that json response in to my table in database..any help for this..?i m working with spring mvc with beans for getter and setter.
I m havving jsp page for usename password mobilenumber.after successful login ,i m getting response from the server in json format. like this

```
{"user id":"dgdsjfhsjf","username":"xyz","password":"hfhgfjg"}
```

i want to insert this data in to my database table  named as user..how can i do this..? this is my user.java

```
@Table(name = "user")
@Column(name = "username")private string username;
@Column(name = "password")private string password;
//getter and setters for username and password
```

i created json object like this

```
String username = user.getUsername();
String password = user.getPassword();
JSONObject jsondata = new JSONObject();
jsondata.put("userName", username);
jsondata.put("Password", password);
```

and i m getting the response body like this,

```
respone = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST,
                    requestEntity, String.class);

            System.out.println(respone.getBody());
```

its in json format,like this

```
{"user id":"hgjfgfffffffffffff","username":"gfg","password":"jfg"}
```

want to convert it into string and insert that value into mysql database and also the user id i m not sending,i m getting this in the json response.so how can i insert one by one value from this json response to my database table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create JsonObject using that json response string,

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm

then you can get the values from jsonObject and copy them to user UserObject and store them in database.

Comment: @Rampeli Srinivas how can i get the single field from the response body..?see my response body,if i want to get the usrid fromthe resposne how can i ?

Comment: Once you create JsonObject you can get the values using key's that is jsonObj.getString(key) you will get the value. go through the tutorial which i have given.

Answer (score 0):

Deserialize the JSON object.

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<user>(jsonString);
```